# Localization with ICU in Spring-MVC using cookie

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization, icu

I need to using ICU ( International Components for Unicode ) Because my app should supports locales that not supported in JDK like "fa_IR".

I found a piece of config that provides this feature using Spring and Cookie.

```
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <beans:property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"/>
    <beans:property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"/>
</beans:bean>

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="locale" />
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>
```

Is there any way using similar config for ICU ?

If this config impossible is it any other way (say changing controller and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

Example in op's question is configuration of `CookieLocaleResolver` that allows you to resolve requested locale from a cookie (it's resolved from `Accept-Language` header by default) and `LocaleChangeInterceptor` that allows you to change locale by a request.

ICU does not have anything to do with that. ICU is library that allows you to format and translate messages. It doesn't care about locale change that's Spring stuff.

I assume that you want to use ICU for locale aware message formatting as a replacement of Java's `java.text.MessageFormat` class.

Spring uses `MessageFormat` in it's `MessageSourceSupport` class that is extended by `AbstractMessageSource` which is also extended by `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.

To incorporate ICU's `com.ibm.icu.text.MessageFormat` class in your application you will have to implement your own `MessageSrouce` class which provides MessageFormats. And then configure your template engine to use it. Following snippet shows Thymeleaf configuration with custom `MessageSource`.

```
SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
// ...
engine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(myCustomMessageSource);
return engine;
```

Well at least I didn't find better solution yet.

Maybe you will be interested in my article [Spring Boot internationalisation with database stored messages and IBM ICU](http://vkuzel.blogspot.cz/2016/05/spring-boot-internationalisation-with.html)

Comment: https://github.com/transferwise/spring-icu implements an ICU compliant message source which can be used as in your example